# CheckBox on a GridView

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

I have a grid view that has 3 columns(Name, Address, Status)  and a checkbox.The Status has 3 properties, Active, Pending, and Disabled. The page load all the information from the database. When loading the page, only accounts that are ACTIVE should be displayed (and the checkbox should remain unchecked)
When clicking the checkbox, the page should load the DISABLED, along with the accounts already displayed When the page loads for the first time.

Aspx:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ChkBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="cbShowAllColumn_Changed" TextAlign="Right" Text="Show All"/>
                    </asp:Panel>
```

Code behind:

```
            protected void cbShowColumn_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string columnName = (sender as CheckBox).ID.Substring(1);
                gvTest.Columns[(int)Enum.Parse(typeof(AccountColumns), columnName)].Visible = (sender as CheckBox).Checked;
            }

            protected void cbShowAllColumn_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               bool _checked = (sender as CheckBox).Checked;

               foreach (Control ctrl in pAccount.Controls)
                 if (ctrl is CheckBox)
                 {
                   (ctrl as CheckBox).Checked = _checked;
                   gvMain.Columns[(int)Enum.Parse(typeof(AccountColumns), (ctrl as CheckBox).ID.Substring(2))].Visible = _checked;
                 }

           }
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @AngelEyes,I am trying to display the status based on the check box. when it is unchecked it will display all the 3 status when it's checked only shows Active

Answer (score 0):

I compiled a small asp .net page to do what you asked.

**Note:** In your project, you should probably take the "source" out of the BindGrid method, so that you don't "get" the data from scratch every time the page is posted back to. I did it that way because I used an anonymous type.

**Note #2** I converted an int to your enum and then to a string. Since you use real data you should handle that differently, by using the enum itself.

Markup:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ChkBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="cbShowAllColumn_Changed" TextAlign="Right" Text="Show All"/>
    <br/>
    <asp:gridview ID="gvMain" runat="server" >

    </asp:gridview>
```

Codebehind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindGrid(false);
    }


    private void BindGrid(bool showActiveOnly)
    {
         var source = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
                                  .Select(number => new { number, status = (Enum.ToObject(typeof(Statuses), number % 3)).ToString() });

        var filteredSource = source.Where(x => x.status == "Active" || !showActiveOnly);

        gvMain.DataSource = filteredSource;
        gvMain.DataBind();
    }


    protected void cbShowAllColumn_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool _checked = (sender as CheckBox).Checked;

        BindGrid(_checked);
    }

    private enum Statuses
    {
        Active,
        Pending,
        Disabled
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The page already loads all the info from the DB from cachedLists. I was thinking to create a new list to bind to the gridview based on that and perform in the new list  filtering that are necessary. Also, I am ngetting error (The data source does not support server-side data paging.) on gvMain.DataBind()

Comment: @user3495554 I'm not sure I understand the question, now.
Per my answer, you can filter with LINQ.
If you want help with an exception, post a new question about it.

Comment: In the note you said"In your project, you should probably take the "source" out of the BindGrid method, so that you don't "get" the data from scratch every time the page is posted back to. I did it that way because I used an anonymous type". so what should I use for the source?

Comment: What I meant was that for my convenience, I put the code that populates the source, in the Bind method. Since you get your data from the DB, it would be wrong to get it over and over again, just to filter it.
The proper way would be to get the data once, and then just filter it accordingly.
I'm not familiar with "cachedLists", so I can't help you there - but if you are getting the data just once, then you did it correctly.